# UDP not load balancing on aks-engine?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I deployed simple udp server [example](http://microsoft.com/developerblog/2017/06/28/scaling-udp-workloads-with-kubernetes) but can see incoming traffic only 1 of 5 pods (with **kubectl logs 'udp-server-deployment-XXX'** ). I tried it on Azure aks-engine , why it is never load balancing ?

```
$ kubectl get pods | grep udp-server

udp-server-deployment-6f87f5c9-4mhpm 1/1 Running 0 4m

udp-server-deployment-6f87f5c9-5lqkm 1/1 Running 0 4m

udp-server-deployment-6f87f5c9-5x92x 1/1 Running 0 4m

udp-server-deployment-6f87f5c9-smb8g 1/1 Running 0 4m

udp-server-deployment-6f87f5c9-tszgs 1/1 Running 0 4m
```

It doesn't help if load balance on public IP neither internal (*service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"*) Try yourself, if you have 'loggen' (linux syslog generator) handy :

```
git clone https://github.com/jpoon/kubernetes-udp.git

cd kubernetes-udp

kubectl create -f server.yaml

loggen --inet --dgram --size 300 --rate 10 --interval 10 <IPAddress of udp-server-service > 10001

kubectl logs udp-server-deployment-6f87f5c9-xxx (5 times)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only confirm from my side, that I share the same observations as you. LoadBalancing does not kick in when using UDP protocol, no matter of underlying service port type (ClusterIP, NodePort, or LoadBalancer), I checked it on both Azure and GCP.

I think it`s all about the fact that:

> A UDP server can’t act as health probe in itself, because UDP doesn’t
>   have acknowledgements that the load balancer could check so an
>   additional component is needed

as mentioned in [this](https://blog.vjrantal.net/2017/03/16/using-azure-load-balancer-to-distribute-udp-traffic/) blog post.